# Why does the airflow in the mid-stratosphere of the northern hemisphere rotate FASTER than the earth?

Tags: earth, atmospheric-science

I have been playing around with [this nice visualisation](http://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/isobaric/10hPa/orthographic=-1.45,54.02,482) and noticed that in the mid-stratosphere (P=10hPa), the airflow around the equator and south of it is in the opposite direction to the earth's rotation [airflow relative to a fixed point on the surface], as one would expect.

In the northern hemisphere though (centered around Svalbard) the air flow is in the same direction as the rotation of the ground below and is at high velocity.  This seems somewhat counter-intuitive - what is the reason for it?

[image]

Comment: Hrm, no idea how I didn't see this question earlier! What is the timescale for the data in the image? I assume it is time-averaged, but how long is the average?

Comment: It's a simulation, I'm not sure what the timescale is.  Feel free to play with it on the link in the question :)  Options are in the bottom left (click EARTH)

Comment: If air moves toward the east at all, it is moving faster than the earth, if the reference is the earth's surface. But I agree, it is surprising. There's a lot about that simulation I don't understand. It seems to disagree with what I thought was basic circulation of air on the earth.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey There's a bunch of things happening there. But as I posted in my answer, moving east is expected just from a kinematics perspective. But what you see there is also acceleration due to the contraction caused by the blockage of that vortex centered in the view. And so there can be much more complicated structures and patterns than "wind goes X direction at Y lattitude" when you are looking at small time-averages like this. When you look at climatological scales (decade+), you'll see patterns that look more like the image in my answer.

Comment: @tpg2114: I appreciate what you're saying. I looked at the simulation, and the entire southern hemisphere has a broad easterly flow, and the equator is all westerly. This makes me doubt the simulation.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey This is from the [Global Forecast System model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Forecast_System) and while it has some drawbacks/inaccuracies (which is why our weather forecast isn't 100% accurate), it's still a pretty good model. If you look at the link, you're looking at the 10 hPa altitude and that's very high up. Check what's going on at lower levels, say, 250 hPa and you'll see a very traditional westerly in both hemispheres. You'll also see a very coherent jet stream in the south while the north does not show a strong one. This will change the behavior at all heights.

Comment: If you look at what's happening at the 10 hPa level, you see a strong southern flow from the north pole. This is because at lower altitudes, there is a strong northern flow. When all this northern flow gets to the pole, it creates an updraft which has to then spread southward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's all kinds of awesome and complicated stuff going on in that image... so let's look at a much simpler one to see what you mean ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westerlies)):

[image]

At the equator, the predominant wind direction is easterly, or opposite the direction of Earth rotation. Away from the equator, north of 30 degrees, the winds are primarily westerly, with the direction of rotation, which means the atmosphere is moving faster there than the Earth.

If we stopped the Earth from rotating, then the air would flow from the equator to the poles just based on temperature gradients. However, because the Earth is rotation, there is a [Coriolis force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect) that acts on the air as it moves. This causes northward motion to turn towards the east (generating westerly winds).

This is what causes the wind in the northern hemisphere to accelerate to the east. If you are closer to the equator, the wind will be coming from a more south-westerly direction because the Coriolis effect is weaker. If you are closer to the north pole, the wind will be coming from almost due west.

Comment: My question had been open for a year with no responses and you just answered it completely with physics so basic that I'm embarrassed I hadn't figured it out myself in that time!  Thanks!

Comment: @MarkKCowan A year! No wonder I missed it! When I saw the date, I completely read that as like... 20 days ago. I really need to pay closer attention. I hope you didn't need an answer way sooner :)