# Why doesn't Earth's atmosphere form bands due to different rotational speeds?

Tags: earth, atmospheric-science, weather

If the Earth's atmosphere is rotating at the same speed as Earth, then the atmosphere must be rotating much faster at the equator than at the poles. If you spin a ball covered in oil, it will form rings. Also Jupiter has rings. So why doesn't the Earth have rings of weather too?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but you may find this (and the linked website) interesting:

http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94105/

Answer (score 32):

The short answer is -- there are bands! They behave very similar to the bands on Jupiter, but are not as pronounced. And we don't have a really unappealing colored atmosphere to show us what the bands look like.

Here is an example of what they look like ([source](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Earth_Global_Circulation.jpg)):

[image]

There are two bands along each side of the equator. Another set of bands starts 30 degrees north and south of the equator. And another band starts 30 degrees further north and south (at 60 degrees total).

You'll also note that these differences in wind in the same direction of rotation also causes wind to form in the north-south direction. All of this is what drives the major weather systems.

Consider the US. Weather systems will *typically* move from west to east. Atlantic hurricanes form in the tropical band off the coast of Africa. They form here because the wind is relatively calm and there is little north/south shearing. They then move westward in the tropical band while also moving north due to the Coriolis forces. As they move north, they begin to encounter the westerly winds that are characteristic of the mid-latitude cell. This will eventually turn them around so they move north-east along the US coastline until turning due-east and moving towards Europe (which in turn induces a southward drift due to Coriolis forces).

Here are what several of these hurricane paths look like ([source](http://earthzine.org/2010/12/28/from-preparation-to-response-coastal-decision-support-during-the-caribbean-hurricane-season-2010-with-radarsat-2/)):

[image]

These bands are not typically readily apparent. Mostly this is because our atmosphere is transparent so we have no way to "visualize" the bands. It is possible to sometimes capture bands however. A band of rainfall in the intertropical convergence zone around the equator is captured in this GOES satellite image ([source](https://alatlatequator.wordpress.com/page/2/)):

[image]

Also, these bands are climatological features and not meteorological features. This means their structure is not always apparent instantaneously but appear in a time-averaged view of the atmosphere. It turns out that NOAA released a [time-lapsed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieILUnkdD90) of 10 years worth of GOES-12 images and the bands become pretty apparent!

@DavidHammen found [another great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7QttjGu628&t=0m40s) looking at the infrared signature caused by water vapor in the air by the GOES-13 satellite shows the bands better than looking at the visible cloud cover.

Comment: Thank you that is very interesting. But we do have clouds, so why don't the clouds form bands? I have never seen any photo of Earth from space that shows any kind of banding at all.

Comment: @KellyClifford-Banks We do, but it's very rare that they would blanket an entire region. Also, it highlights and important distinction between *weather* and *climate*. We have these bands in the atmosphere in a climatological sense -- when you take a time average of the atmosphere, you will see the bands. If you took an instantaneous snapshot of the atmosphere right now, bands would not be very evident (even with clouds or some other way to "see" it).

Comment: I would love to see a time lapse movie of Earth that shows this! Where can I find that?

Comment: That is a computer generated image right?

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see why there isn't much more banding. i mean there is a difference of 1000km/h at the equator to the poles. surely the drag effect would cause the clouds / atmnosphere (they are the same thing right?) to form huge spirals around the earth

Comment: @KellyClifford-Banks Clouds will only be present where water vapor is present in sufficient amounts. One band of fast moving air aloft is the subtropical jetstream which results from conservation of angular momentum as air rises up over the equator and toward the poles (eventually becoming westerly due to coriolis).

Comment: @KellyClifford-Banks Clouds are like a tracer for the atmosphere if it helps you think that way. It's the same as dropping some food coloring in water to see how it moves. I'll try to think about how the mean velocity of the bands is determined and get back to you.

Comment: The "bands" (Hadley cells, Ferrel cells, and polar cells) are much more obvious in the infrared, particularly the water vapor channel. Here's a link to a time lapsed water vapor channel video at youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7QttjGu628&t=0m40s .

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks! I added it to the answer in case the comments get removed at some point. Man, atmospheric fluid dynamics are awesome...

Comment: Our atmosphere is transparent at visible wavelengths but not for most of the infrared, in particular not beyond 12µm.  Perhaps one could find some full-disk snapshot taken in infrared or microwave at an instant where the bands are particularly visible.

Comment: @gerrit That would be pretty awesome. I could search for images all day for this answer though :) I need to get some real work done, but if you (or somebody else) finds some great images, let me know and I can incorporate it.

Comment: Is this at all related to the jet stream? e.g. could one consider the jet stream a "band" in OPs sense?

Comment: @hd1 It is related, although the jet stream is a transient phenomenon. If you look at [the jet stream in a short time](http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/064/963/original/jet-stream.jpg), it would have a snake-like appearance. If you took an average over many years of the jet stream, it would [look something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_stream#mediaviewer/File:Jetstreamconfig.jpg) where it begins to form a "band".

Comment: IF the equator rotates at 1,600 km/h and 0 km/h at the poles, then each degree of latitude above and below the equator must be rotating at approx 17 km/h slower. Considering that average wind speeds are around 10 km/h, why is this spiralling not much more apparent?

Comment: I don't see any bands. And the image of Earth you added is the effect of El Nino and that forms totally differently. Warm air goes towards Japan in the winter and North is pushing down because of the low pressure. Nothing to do with Earth rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that on Jupiter bands are more evidente because the rotational speed of the planet is much bigger. Jupiter has a rotation period of about 11 hours and a radius 12 times that of earth.